# User management missing after migration to new host

Tags: users, user-meta, migration

I just moved my WordPress 3.9 site to a different host by making a mysql dump and restoring it on the new server and uploading the files over. Pretty standard.

However, now I've lost the ability to manage users. On the old server, the left hand menu in the dashboard reads

- Appearance
- Plugins
- Users
- etc...

But the new site reads,

- Appearance
- Plugins
- Profile
- etc...

If I manually try to navigate to the `/wp-admin/users.php` page, I get the "Cheatin', huh?" message.

I checked the `wp_usermeta` table and it is exactly the same on the new database as the old database. What happened? How do I restore the user management section.

Comment: Did tou change the table prefix?

Comment: Yes. I changed the prefix, but I also updated the usermeta table to use the updated table prefix. Maybe I should change it back?

Comment: So you changed all meta keys for `[old_prefix]_capabilities` to `[new_prefix]_capabilities`? Don't forget the same for `[prefix]_user_level` as well as `[prefix]_roles` in the options table!